# I can't run kdenlive appimage

Tags: kdenlive

I can't run kdenlive appimage (Ubuntu 18.04,kdenlive-18.12.1b-x86_64.appimage, the same applies to version 19.x.x).

I get the following message:

```
$ sudo ./kdenlive-18.12.1b-x86_64.appimage 
dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2

AppImages require FUSE to run. 
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
```

I removed fuse and libfuse2 and reinstalled them but that did not help. 
This is my office computer and kdenlive runs just fine on my computer at home. I don't know what I am missing...

Answer (score 0):

I did some research.
It looks that for some reason, not quite clear to me, only the 32 bit packages of libfuse2 and fuse were installed on my computer. After installing the 64 bit packages the kdenlive appimage runs flawless.

Answer (score 0):

Move it to the desktop, right-click it, click "Open With Other Application", scroll down until you see the app "Run Software". Click that, and then click "Open". Your .AppImage file will now open. Note that I did this on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I recommend you download this and upgrade to it using a bootable usb.
I also reccomend using Etcher to make the bootable usb. Also note that Etcher is an AppImage file too, so follow the instructions I gave to open the AppImage. Hope this helps!

Ubuntu20.04 LTS ISO: https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
Etcher AppImage: https://www.balena.io/Etcher

(both free)